# Docker "ImportError: No module named boto" when Boto is installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, boto3

In my alpine based docker image, I have installed boto3.output of dockerbuild from docker-compose.

```
  Running setup.py install for s3cmd: started
    Running setup.py install for s3cmd: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed awscli-1.14.5 **boto3-1.13.15** botocore-1.8.9 colorama-0.3.7 docutils-0.16 futures-3.3.0 jmespath-0.10.0 pyasn1-0.4.8 python-dateutil-2.8.1  pyyaml-5.3.1 rsa-3.4.2 s3cmd-2.0.1 s3transfer-0.1.13 six-1.15.0
```

snippet of dockerfile looks like below,

```
FROM alpine:3.6
RUN apk -v --update add \
        python3 \
        py-pip \
        groff \
        less \
        mailcap \
        curl \
        jq && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir awscli==1.14.5 s3cmd==2.0.1 boto3 pyyaml && \
    apk -v --purge del py-pip && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

when I try to execute my python package via docker-compose using same Dockerfile: 
its says

```
setup-application_1  |   File "test_cf_create_or_update.py", line 1, in <module>
setup-application_1  |     import boto3
setup-application_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
localstack_setup-application_1 exited with code 1
```

I don't know, how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
pip3 install boto3 -t .
```

It seems that boto is not going to the right target, with "t" flag and ".", you make sure it is seen by all!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are installing `python3`, you should be using `pip3`:

```
   pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
   pip3 install --no-cache-dir awscli==1.14.5 s3cmd==2.0.1 boto3 pyyaml && \
```

And the in the container you will use `python3` to execute your script.

Also worth noting is the fact that since you have fixed the versions of `awscli` and `s3cmd`, you will be getting **warnings** about either too old or too new libraries when building the docker image.

Comment: maybe you are right, pip3 is the culprit here. and inside the container, I'm using python3 to call my script.Let me change and test it.

Comment: yes, I can safely say that, this was the issue. after suing pip3 everything went fine.Thanks